# How to use multiple forms or objects using jQuery Form Plugin?

Tags: jquery, forms, plugins

I've done a lot of searches and can't find exactly what I'm trying to do, although it relates to similarly titled posts that have already been answered.

I'm using the jQuery Form Plugin.

One input/text box and a search button displays results in a div lower on the page.

However, I want to add 3 buttons beneath the first input area that are "popular tags" (where the value represented as the text on the button are different from eachother) and when one is clicked on, the results in the div below get modified according to the name value of the button.

My question is that I don't know how to utilize separate objects or forms to accomplish it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var options = { 
    target:     '#searchResults', 
    url:        'ajax/getResults.php', 
    type:   'POST',
};
$('#searchForm').ajaxForm(options);
});
```

Nothing on the web says how to add a different object or element, such as:

```
var options2 = { //...
```

And then how to bind it. Would it be:

```
$('#searchForm').ajaxForm(options, options2);
```

OR

```
$('#searchForm').ajaxForm(options);
$('#searchForm').ajaxForm(options2);
```

OR something else?

Then, I saw one that mentions how to add two forms, such as:

```
$('#searchForm1','#searchForm2').ajaxForm(options);
```

But, that is confusing because why would two different forms both have the same var options and if they don't, again, how does it all get involved and etc.?

The "getResults.php" uses

```
$searchedTerm = $_REQUEST['searchBox'];
```

To get what was entered in that box to feed the div lower on the age.

If I try to put a second submit button and get its value, using the same request,

```
$popTagBtn1 = $_REQUEST['popTagBtnNameValue1']; //name and id of second button in form
```

it returns an empty value, when using

```
echo $_REQUEST['popTagBtnNameValue1'];
```

If I try to separate out using multiple forms... again, I don't know how to properly bind them and get it to actually echo the value or name of the other button.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var allForms = $("form");
```

This get all the forms in array

Comment: im not sure where that would go, why, what you'd do after you'd add that, and/or if either parts (allForms or form) in your example would stay as is or get modified to match existing pieces

Comment: and, why an array would be needed when im trying to figure out what code to use to bind the second object in ajax to the right spot